# Lookup Threshold value override using C# code..!

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

In Production Environment, the Lookup Threshold value set to Default :12.
Because of this Value my code give me an error.
So If increase this value to 20 then my code works fine.
So i want to override this value using C# code.so my code will run fine even if they set to 12.